# Extrapolate userbase growth rate linear + viral

Tags: math

Assume you have ***n*** users and know that *n* grows by a fixed number of users ***c*** per day and viral growth rate of ***k*** per day, where *k* is expressed as a percentage of *n*.

How can you tell how many days it will take for the userbase to grow to size ***x***, where *x* > *n*?

This is a compound interest problem, but I don't know how to do it with the addition of the constant factor *c*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't mind fractional users... If *k* is expressed as a decimal (so a growth rate of 5% is *k*=1.05), then the formula is:

> *days*=log<sub>*k*</sub>(((1-*k*) *x* - *c*) / ((1-*k*) *n* - *c*))

For instance, suppose your initial userbase is 5; you grow constantly by 3 users per day, and virally by 5% per day; and your target is 35 users. Then

> *days*=log<sub>1.05</sub>(((-0.05)*35 - 3) / ((-0.05)*5 - 3)) = **7.78**.

Running the process in Excel, you can see that, indeed, day 7 gives you 31.5 users, and day 8 36 users.

Derivation:

Denote the number of users after *d* days as *n_d*. Then:

*n<sub>1</sub>* = *kn* + *c*

*n<sub>2</sub>* = *kn<sub>1</sub>* + *c* = *k*( *kn* + *c*) + *c* = *k<sup>2</sup>n* + (*k* + 1)*c*

*n<sub>3</sub>* = *kn<sub>2</sub>* + *c* = *k*( *k<sup>2</sup>n* + (*k* + 1)*c*) + *c* = *k<sup>3</sup>n* + (*k*<sup>2</sup> + *k* + 1)*c*

...

*n<sub>d</sub>* = *k<sup>d</sup>n* + SUM<sub>i=0,*d*-1</sub>(*k<sup>i</sup>c*)

Now, the SUM is a geometric series. The sum of that geometric series is easily derivable (or found on Wikipedia!) to be *c*(1 - *k<sup>d</sup>*)/(1 - *k*).

So:

*n<sub>d</sub>* = *k<sup>d</sup>n* + *c*(1 - *k<sup>d</sup>*)/(1 - *k*)

= *k<sup>d</sup>n* + *c*/(1 - *k*) - *ck<sup>d</sup>*/(1 - *k*)

= *k<sup>d</sup>*( *n* - *c*/(1 - *k*)) + *c*/(1 - *k*)

So

*k<sup>d</sup>* = (*n<sub>d</sub>* - *c*/(1 - *k*)) / (*n* - *c*/(1 - *k*))

= ((1 - *k*) *n<sub>d</sub>* - *c*) / ((1 - *k*) *n* - *c*)

So

*d* = log<sub>*k*</sub>(((1 - *k*) *n<sub>d</sub>* - *c*) / ((1 - *k*) *n* - *c*))

Comment: wait, in the example you put 1-k as equal to both -0.05 and -0.95

Comment: Frankly, if that's the only typo I've made, I'll be astonished. SO is _not_ built for writing maths.